# Closed invariant subspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Why does the invariant subspace problem only ask about closed invariant subpaces? I understand that if $W$ is an invariant subspace then the closure of $W$ is also invariant but if $W$ is dense in the space, the closure of $W$ is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is easy to find non-closed subspace:

Take $\operatorname{LinSpan}(e, Ae, A^2e, \dots)$ where span is taken in lineary-algebraic sense.

Comment: how do we know that's its not equal to the whole space?

Comment: It has countable dimension in algebraic sense.

Comment: can you explain any further?

Comment: hilbert space has uncountable dimension (in the algebraic sense) and the space above has finite or countable basis by definition.

Comment: what about for a banach space

Comment: in banach space too. It is a corollary of Baire theorem: complete space can not be a union of finite-dimensional subspaces because they are nowhere dense.